# PHP - Possible to call member function of object stored in an array?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and spent some time searching for a similar question, but none seemed to quite answer it for me.

I have an array of Objects (a class I created called StatusMessage) and I want to access a member function of each object in the array. I am able to do this using a foreach loop, but I only need to access the first 10 objects (they are sorted) so I am trying to use a for loop. When I make the member function calls, I get a fatal error about not being able to call member functions on non-objects. Do the StatusMessage objects in $statObjs need to be cast or something?

Any suggestions?

```
function collectStatuses($statusesAPI){

    $statusObjects = Array();   
    foreach($statusesAPI as $status)
    {
      //StatusMessage is a class I created
    array_push($statusObjects, new StatusMessage($status));             
    }           
    return $statusObjects;
}

//$statutuses[data] was populated further up
$statObjs = collectStatuses($statuses[data]);

//This loop works, but prints all StatusMessage objects in $statObjs 
foreach ($statObjs as $value) {
  //getInteractions() and getMessages() are both member functions of the StatusMessage class I created.
  echo '[' . $value->getInteractions() . '] ' .  $value->getMessage();
}

//This loop doesn't work. Throws the error mentioned above
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

  echo '[' . $statObjs[$i]->getInteractions() . '] ' .  $statObjs[$i]->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing $s. I was trying to clean-up the code for this post and over did it. However, in the actual code, there are no missing dollar signs. The only error I receive is inside the for loop, when trying to call the member functions.

Comment: Then it is probably what @Chris says and you have less than 10 objects in the array. Do a `print_r($statObjs)` or `echo count($statObjs)` before and check it.

Comment: I am having this exact issue. Did you ever figure it out? Everyone's answers seem to indicate that you probably don't have 10 items in your array of objects, but I don't think that's it. I have an array with only one object in it, and I can't access its member functions using $arr[0] or current($arr) -- only if I use foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is worth writing a simple test, saving to a separate file, and then running script through the PHP interpreter from the command-line. When debugging complicated code, it is easy to bark up the wrong tree. If you are feeling ambitious, you can take it one step further and explore writing unit tests using PHPUnit.

```
<?php

$statuses = array(
    'test1', 
    'test2', 
    'test3', 
    'test4', 
    'test5', 
    'test6', 
    'test7', 
    'test8',
    'test9',
    'test10',
    'test11'
);


class StatusMessage {
    private $status;
    function __construct($status) {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    function getInteractions() {
        return $this->status . " interactions";
    }

    function getMessage() {
        return $this->status . " messages";
    }

}

function collectStatuses($statusesAPI){

    $statusObjects = Array();   
    foreach($statusesAPI as $status)
    {
      //StatusMessage is a class I created
    array_push($statusObjects, new StatusMessage($status));             
    }           
    return $statusObjects;
}

//$statutuses[data] was populated further up
$statObjs = collectStatuses($statuses);

//This loop works, but prints all StatusMessage objects in $statObjs 
foreach ($statObjs as $value) {
    //getInteractions() and getMessages() are both member functions of the StatusMessage class I created.
    echo '[' . $value->getInteractions() . '] ' .  $value->getMessage() . "\n";
}

//This loop doesn't work. Throws the error mentioned above
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo '[' . $statObjs[$i]->getInteractions() . '] ' .  $statObjs[$i]->getMessage() . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that the actual code? There are a couple of mistakes.

Three of the 'i' variables in that last loop are missing dollar signs.

```
$i<10
$statObjs[$i]->
$statObjs[$i]->
```

You are incrementing $j, when you want to increment $i   ($i++)

Also, if there aren't 10 status messages, you may want to count $i < min(10, $statObjs.length)

Hope this helps,

Chris

Comment: Good point regarding the number of objects. However, `$statObjs.length` is JavaScript, not PHP. You have to do `count($statObjs)`. I nowhere see `$j`, I think you misread this.

Comment: I think he edited the code, as the dollar signs are now in, and the $j has been switched to $i.

Comment: No, I didn't see the `$j` before either. But yes, he added the dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend just trying, within the loop

```
$statusObject = $statObjs[$i];
print_r($statusObject);
```

and then perhaps running a  to see if the object's actually right there.  Sometimes I feel php doesn't treat object references as first class objects when you reference them directly from the array, unlike the java or other language you're used to ;).

This also makes your experiment a little more scientific, as your referencing a $variable directly without the $variable['ArrayFluff'] at the end of it.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $statusObject = $statObjs[$i];
  echo '[' . $statusObject->getInteractions() . '] ' .  $statusObject->getMessage();
//I'm fairly confident this will work =]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have stated seems to indicate to me that the array is not set all the way up to 10.  Are you also getting undefined key notices (`error_reporting(E_ALL)` to check).

If this is the problem, you can use [`array_slice()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the sub-array that you need:

```
foreach (array_slice($statObjs, 0, 10) as $obj) {
   echo "[{$obj->getInteractions()}] {$obj->getMessage()}";
}
```

Even if `$statObjs` has less than 10 indeces, array_slice will return it.  Otherwise, it returns only the first 10.

Answer (score -1):

Now that you've incorporated in the suggestions I made in my previous post, that code is now working for me. Are you using PHP 5 or later?